# Does UINT_MAX have all bits set to 1?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

This question is asked before but I am still confused.

I know that

```
unsigned int a = -1;
```

would be `UINT_MAX`. But it is not because all bits of -1 is set. C11 says

> if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type

So lets say `UINT_MAX` is 100 (I know it should be greater then 2^16-1 but lets ignore this for now)

```
unsigned int a = -1; // will be
unsigned int a = -1 + UINT_MAX + 1; // 100 = UINT_MAX
```

Standard only says `UINT_MAX >= 2^16-1`. But does it say anywhere it should be 2^n-1?

Also is answer different in C++?

Comment: I think that the standard mostly leaves the exact bit representation of values unspecified (or platform dependent).  There are (have been) some really strange architectures out there.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In C, the maximum value for an unsigned integer must be in the form<sup>1</sup>: 2<sup>*N*</sup> - 1.

Thus all *value* bits of the value UINT_MAX will be set to 1. There may be *padding* bits, whose values are unspecified.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.6.2 Integer types 1)
For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need not be any of the latter). If there are *N* value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2 between 1 and 2<sup>*N*−1</sup> , so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from 0 to 2<sup>*N*</sup>−1 using a pure binary representation; this shall be known as the value representation. The values of any padding bits are unspecified.

Comment: Huh.  I guess you can't write a C compiler for a ternary computer.

Comment: Well... you *could*, it would just suck :P

Comment: @Mark: You just have to emulate 8-bit-base-2 byte-by-byte overflows. So basically: the resulting binary would have to run in a base-2 emulator.

Answer (score 11):

No, not quite.

An unsigned type can consist of *value bits* and *padding bits*.

You are correct that the value bits will always be set to 1 for the maximum value, but the specific values of the padding bits is left to the implementation. So this means that UINT_MAX needs to be a *Mersenne number*. Other requirements state it can't be less than 65535.

C and C++ are equivalent in this respect.

Comment: But that still requires UINT_MAX must be of the form 2^n - 1, for some n >= 16.

Comment: Indeed it does: i.e. a Mersenne number (not necessarily prime), greater than or equal to 65535.

Comment: I can't find anything in the C++14 standard about fundamental types having any padding bits.  The only think I can see referencing the C standard in `[basic.fundamental]` is it must respect C 5.2.4.2.1 which is the limits sections.

Comment: Minor nitpick: It may be good to clarify the reference to the Mersenne numbers as [the term is usually reserved for 2^p-1](https://oeis.org/A000225) with *p* prime. Though *p* is often generalised, with abuse of notation, to every positive integer.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct to say that by the definition of conversions, -1 converted to unsigned int is guaranteed to be UINT_MAX. It hasn't anything to do with any bit patterns. If there was an implementation where UINT_MAX was 100, then -1 converted to unsigned int would be 100.

There are reasons why UINT_MAX cannot be 100: One because it must be ≥ 2^16-1, but that would allow UINT_MAX = 1,000,000. Second, because unsigned int must have a binary representation with some fixed number n of value bits, so UINT_MAX = 2^n - 1.

It *is* possible that INT_MAX = 2^31 - 1 and UINT_MAX = 2^31 - 1 (not 2^32 - 1 as it is usually). In that case -1 would have 32 bits set; -1 cast to unsigned int would be 2^31 - 1 and have only 31 bits set.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: -1 in 1+31-bit `signed int` has 32 bits set _if implementation uses two's complement_, which practically all machines since the mid-'80s do for integers, but 6.2.6.2p2 _allows_ ones' complement or sign and magnitude which would have 31 bits and 2 bits respectively.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: A system with 32-bit two's-complement signed integer would almost certainly have a 32-bit unsigned integer as well.  Just about the only reason that a non-contrived implementation would have an `unsigned` type with fewer possible values than the corresponding signed type would be that hardware was limited to a form of signed arithmetic which couldn't accommodate 2ⁿ distinct values.